# Problem with latest version of MacTex

Tags: errors, compiling, texmaker

I've just installed the latest version of MacTex on my MacBookAir (2020) and for some specific cls file the compiler is giving me the following error:

```
\scratchcounter=\count286
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii:136: Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.136 ...csname newcount\endcsname \scratchcounter
```

Before the update everything was running nicely...

Any ideas about what may be causing this?

Comment: is your mactex installation up to date? Note that the MacTeX you install is a snapshot from last year, so it probably need to be updated. Other than you we probably need some more information about what it is you are compiling that now gives an error.

Comment: I remember that there were updates to context over the year since TeX Live 2020 was there leased. Please update using tomorrow or TeX Live Utility.